# Can't deploy an app to Intune store via graph API - DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All is an invalid scope?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We want to enable uploading apps to the Intune store via an API.
I saw [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/LOB_Application), and want to do something similar in JS, so I've tried using the same REST calls.
The problem is, I can't seem to make the `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps` request properly - I always get 401. When making the same request via the Graph API Explorer it works fine.

I tried fixing my permissions, and I'm kinda stuck getting the correct token.
I did the following steps with an admin account, on both the "common" and our own tennant:

1. Called the admin consent -  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/nativeflow.onmicrosoft.com/adminconsent?client_id=<ID>&redirect_uri=<URI>`
2. Got authorization from the user - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<ID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<URI>&response_mode=query&scope=DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All`
3. POST request to get the actual token - 
   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/nativeflow.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

   with the following body:

   ```
   client_id: <ID>
   scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
   client_secret: <secret>
   grant_type: client_credentials
   requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
   code: <The code I got in step 2>
   ```

I tried changing the scope in step 3 to `https://graph.microsoft.com/DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All` or simply to `DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All`, but it says that it's not a valid scope.

I got a token in step 3, but when I try calling the actual API I receive this error:

```
{
  ErrorCode:"Forbidden",
  Message:{
    _version: 3,
    Message: "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 7b5c3841-976d-4509-b946-f7fdabd047d7 - Url: https://fef.msub02.manage.microsoft.com/StatelessAppMetadataFEService/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps?api-version=5018-05-02",
    CustomApiErrorPhrase: "", 
    RetryAfter: null, 
    ErrorSourceService: "", 
    HttpHeaders: {"WWW-Authenticate":"Bearer realm=urn:intune:service,f0f3c450-59bf-4f0d-b1b2-0ef84ddfe3c7"}
  },
  Target:null,
  Details:null,
  InnerError:null,
  InstanceAnnotations:[]
}
```

So yeah, I'm pretty much stuck. Anyone have any experience with it? I've tried making the calls in Postman, curl and via code, but nothing works.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on:

1. You're using the [Authorization Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) Grant workflow but requesting [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds).
2. The scope `Device.ReadWrite.All` is an application scope, it is only applicable to Client Credentials. It isn't a valid Delegated scope so it will return an error when you attempt to authenticate a user (aka delegate) using `Device.ReadWrite.All`.
3. Your body is using `key:value` but it should be using standard form encoding (`key=value`).

To get this working, you need to request a [token *without* a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). This is done by skipping your 2nd step and moving directly to retrieving a token (body line-breaks are only for readability):

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/nativeflow.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={id}
&client_secret={secret}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I've tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error.
Is `Device.ReadWrite.Al` the permission I need? Don't I need `DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All`?


The permissions in my apps are:

**Delegated** - `User.Read` and `DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All`

**Application** - `Application.ReadWrite.All` and `Device.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: For delegated access, you can use `DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All` or `DeviceManagementApps.Read.All`. This requires that you use `authorization_code` rather than `client_credentials` (a token cannot have both App and Delegate scopes). You can find a write up on how to retrieve the token at https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/.